# dialogflow V2 Android SDK

Tags: android, sdk, dialogflow-es

I am new to `Dialogflow`. We are creating a voice enabled bot similar application in Android. We are following the samples and docs from https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-android-client.

When we check the `Dialogflow` site it says that `Dialogflow API V2` has officially launched. It is now the default API for all new Dialogflow agents and all new features will only be released on `V2`. Learn how to migrate your `V1` agents.

In the above GitHub samples and documentation, in the android build gradle file, adding dependency ***compile 'ai.api:sdk:2.0.7@aar'***. Does that means that if we use `2.0.7` means we are using `Dialogflow V2 android SDK`?

Asking because in some sample files it says to add dependency to ***compile 'ai.api:libai:1.6.12'***. So the `1.6.12` > `2.0.7` means v1 to v2?

Can somebody comment it this?

Answer (score 1):

The Android SDK version number is irrelevant to that message. The V2/ V1 versions have to do with the the structure of data from the requests and how they are manipulated from the agent. So unless you have some custom API calls using the latest api.ai library (at the time of this post 1.6.12) is fine. The key differences between the V1 and the V2 is the fulfillment and how the responses from the fulfillment are coming back to your agent. It also puts some more limits to the amount of the responses since they introduced the Enterprise edition. V1 will not be supported in the near future so if you're starting a new agent new, use V2.

For more information check this out: https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v1-v2-migration-guide

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any way to pass, payload, lat, log from android v1 sdk to dialogflow?

Comment: According to the same reference (https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v1-v2-migration-guide-fulfillment#webhook_responses), the "payload" was "data" at v1 so yes

Comment: How can I use v2 in my android app, Is there any way?

Comment: Have you got any solutions?  - @AfinasEM

Comment: @Naveen actually I got some code, but it is in core java. When I update that into Android it is conflicting with our Android libraries.

Comment: I am using v2 fulfillment and use the SDK for the Android App. Just by following the samples here it should work I think: https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-android-client